# How to install/enable Level Editor in 2.78

Tags: add-on

I'm looking for [this Level Editor addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilmS_CeKCuo) but the Google Gods aren't turning up any links/docs.

What's the name of this addon? Does it ship with (even as disabled) 2.78 or do I have to download something (plugin?) to activate it inside of Blender?

Comment: I haven't come across it and yes you would need to download and install the addon if you can find out where to get it. I expect the video is showing an early work in progress of an addon that hasn't been finished or released. As there is no response to requests for a link I wouldn't expect to find it.

Comment: [Blender Level Editor](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239528-Blender-Level-Editor) [File Type: blend BlenderLevelEditor.blend (420.4 KB, 583 views)
](https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=163517&d=1323858947) no have .py file